# How do I stop Visual Studio from messing with my connection strings when publishing?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi

In my appsettings.json, I have this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDB": "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I do not have a Development or Production environment version in the project.

However, when I publish the API to IIS, it creates an appsettings.production.json that looks like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDB": "1dc67b3c"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

This causes the API to fail as it cannot connect to the database using that connection string.

How do I stop Visual Studio from messing with my connection string?

Comment: Did you do anything special with your project? How are you publishing to IIS? I tested and it doesn't have the problem you describe, can you provide a minimal reproducible example along with your publish steps?

Comment: I think it may be the Databases selections on the Publish screen for the folder profile. I have my connection string but also some Authentication:Schemes:Bearer entries, and they all say 1dc67b3c, which makes no sense. It seems at some point it got broken, but although I can choose the correct connection string, after hitting Save and reviewing the settings again, it is back to 1dc67b3c, so something in VS is overwriting it.